# Why won't my binary search work for numbers that are double digits?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binary, binary-search

My binary search only works for single digits. I am trying to run a very simple React program to visualize a binary search but for now, the basic search will not work. Here are all the important parts for that code.

```
function binarySearch(arr, val) {
    let start = 0;
    let end = arr.length - 1;
  
    while (start <= end) {
      let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
  
      if (arr[mid] === val) {
        return mid;
      }
  
      if (val < arr[mid]) {
        end = mid - 1;
      } else {
        start = mid + 1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
 

export const BinarySearch = () => {
    const [outputArea, setOutputArea] = useState('');


    const runSearch = (arr, x) => {
        const searched = binarySearch(arr, x);
        setOutputArea(searched + 1);
    }
    


    return (

        <div>
            Enter List: <input type="text"
                        id="listEntry" />
            Enter Number: <input type="text"
                        id="numberEntry" />

            <button type="button"
            onClick={(e) => runSearch(document.getElementById("listEntry").value.split(","), document.getElementById("numberEntry").value)}
            ></button>

            <textarea name="output"  cols="30" rows="10" value={outputArea}></textarea>



        </div>

    );
```

I tried looking at different versions of the search but no options available have worked. The length of the array does not matter as long as the target number is a single digit.

```js
function binarySearch(arr, val) {
  let start = 0;
  let end = arr.length - 1;

  while (start <= end) {
    let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    if (arr[mid] === val) {
      return mid;
    }

    if (val < arr[mid]) {
      end = mid - 1;
    } else {
      start = mid + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

const runSearch = (arr, x) => {
  return binarySearch(arr, x);
  setOutputArea(searched + 1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Enter List: <input type="text" id="listEntry" /> Enter Number: <input type="text" id="numberEntry" />

  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('output').value = runSearch( document.getElementById('listEntry').value.split(','), document.getElementById('numberEntry').value)">Search</button>

  <textarea id="output" name="output" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>


</div>
```

Comment: Your `function binarySearch` has 2 parameters, but your call-site in `runSearch` passes 4 arguments.

Comment: also it's "length" not "lenght"

Comment: it still returns ([1,6,8,10], 10) as -1

Comment: Binary search only works when the array-being-searched is known to be correctly sorted.  Your program, as is, does not assert that precondition, nor does it attempt to sort it by itself. Secondarily, `HTMLInputElement.value.split` will return `string[]` - not `number[]` - so that's another thing that's going to go wrong...

Comment: I will precondition the sorting part later, that is true though I should've thought of that, thank you! However, all of my tests I have run with them being sorted since I did know it had to be. If I run ([1,6,8,10], 10) it returns the correct placement

Comment: I've made an interactive snippet version of the relevant part of your post (i.e. React is just a distraction here). I hope that is enough to help you figure it out yourself...

Comment: When I use `1,6,8,10` and `10` I get `-1`, not `3`.

Comment: Thank you I do this this, do you see that if you input 1,2,6,7,10 and 10, it returns -1 though? I just dont see why it should be an issue for larger numbers.

Comment: @Big_Guy I told you why: they aren't numbers. `string` values are not `number` values. [The `<` operator does not not behave identically for `number` and `string` arguments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et8xNAc2ic8).

Comment: I do remember this, but if you try and search for 6, you get 2, the correct placement. It seems that it just doesnt work on larger numbers, is this because of the split making strings or something else?

Comment: It's because, as a string, `'10' < '6'`, so your input array is effectively not correctly sorted. If you enter `1,10,6,8` and search for `10` you will get `1`, as expected.

Comment: Change your onclick to `"document.getElementById('output').value = runSearch( document.getElementById('listEntry').value.split(',').map(v => parseInt(v, 10)), parseInt(document.getElementById('numberEntry').value, 10))"`